# Less mixin is not applied with a variable selector

Tags: css, angular, less

I'm trying to write a LESS mixin that accepts two parameters.

First is a position value and second is a CSS selector, second is optional.

```
.mixin-sticky-column-left-fix(@positionLeftWithUnit; @selector: '.action-menu-column') {
  &@{selector} {
    left: @positionLeftWithUnit !important;
  }
}
```

I'm calling this like this in two places.

```
mat-cell, mat-header-cell {
        .mixin-sticky-column-left-fix(443.99px);
        .mixin-sticky-column-left-fix(339.99px; '.left339');
}
```

I expect that the mixin will work and will produce the following style.

```
mat-cell, mat-header-cell {
        &.left339{
          left: 339.99px !important;
        }
        &.action-menu-column {
          left: 443.99px !important;
        }
      }
```

But it is not happening, the mixin is not working and the styles are not applied. I'm using LESS with Angular and Angular CLI.

In dev tools, I'm seeing this.

[image]

I tried multiple ways but can't get this to work. Is this not possible in less? or am I doing something wrong here?